# Compose animation Previews in end state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I have some Jetpack Compose Previews that contain animations. In the side panel, I can only see the initial state of the animation. I know that I can preview the full flow of the animation but is it possible to select what timestamp of the animation should be shown by default in the side panel?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you are asking about, but rather alternative solution is to use `LocalInspectionMode` inside compose function to identify, whether or not this function is called from preview (`LocalInspectionMode.current == true` means it's in preview). That way it's possible to use different logic when in preview.

Example below - in preview mode text is visible right away (alpha is 1f), while in the app text's alpha is animated from 0f to 1f with 1 sec. delay.

```
val inPreviewMode = LocalInspectionMode.current
var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

val animatedAlpha by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = if (inPreviewMode) 1f else if (isVisible) 1f else 0f,
    label = "alpha"
)

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    delay(1000)
    isVisible = true
}

Text(
    text = "Some text",
    modifier = Modifier.alpha(animatedAlpha)
)
```

[Official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/previews#localinspectionmode).

Note that if you run preview on device/emulator, `LocalInspectionMode.current` is false.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. We need to update the code of the composable but at least I think there is a way of reaching the end goal. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score -2):

You can enable the animation preview from the top right of the preview screen.

[image: Android Studio preview]

> Animation Preview currently supports the updateTransition and AnimatedVisibility APIs. To access the latest features, use Animation Preview with Android Studio Flamingo and compose.animation 1.4.3 and higher.
> [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/animation-preview)

Comment: "I know that I can preview the full flow of the animation but is it possible to select what timestamp of the animation should be shown by default in the side panel?" I know that option, I want something to preview it without entering the animation mode.

Comment: @Juanje when you start the animation, a control panel appears below it so you can pause and play the animation and also skip it to whatever timestamp you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I don't want to enter the animation preview. I want if there is an option to show a specific timestamp in the static preview.